# embedded python passing unicode strings

Tags: c++, python, unicode, utf-8

note everything works great if i use Ascii, but:

in my utf8-encoded script i have this:

```
print "frøânçïé"
```

in my embedded C++ i have this:

```
PyObject*        CPython_Script::print(PyObject *args)
{
        PyObject                *resultObjP        = NULL;
        const char                *utf8_strZ        = NULL;

        if (PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &utf8_strZ)) {
                Log(utf8_strZ, false);

                resultObjP = Py_None;
                Py_INCREF(resultObjP);
        }

        return resultObjP;
}
```

Now, i know that my Log() can print utf8 (has for years, very well debugged)

but what it *actually* prints is this:

```
print "frøânçïé"
fr√∏√¢n√ß√Ø√©
```

another method i use looks like this:
    kj_commands.menu("控件", "同步滑帧", "全局无滑帧")
    or
    kj_commands.menu(u"控件", u"同步滑帧", u"全局无滑帧")

and in my C++ i have:

```
SuperString                ScPyObject::GetAs_String()
{
        SuperString                str;

        if (PyUnicode_Check(i_objP)) {
                #if 1
                //        method 1
                {
                        ScPyObject                utf8Str(PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(i_objP));

                        str = utf8Str.GetAs_String();
                }
                #elif 0
                //        method 2
                {
                        UTF8Char                *uniZ = (UTF8Char *)PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(i_objP);

                        str.assign(&uniZ[0], &uniZ[PyUnicode_GET_DATA_SIZE(i_objP)], kCFStringEncodingUTF16);
                }
                #else
                //        method 3
                {
                        UTF32Vec                        charVec(32768); CF_ASSERT(sizeof(UTF32Vec::value_type) == sizeof(wchar_t));
                        PyUnicodeObject                *uniObjP = (PyUnicodeObject *)(i_objP);
                        Py_ssize_t                        sizeL(PyUnicode_AsWideChar(uniObjP, (wchar_t *)&charVec[0], charVec.size()));

                        charVec.resize(sizeL);
                        charVec.push_back(0);
                        str.Set(SuperString(&charVec[0]));
                }
                #endif
        } else {
                str.Set(uc(PyString_AsString(i_objP)));
        }

        Log(str.utf8Z());

        return str;
}
```

for the string, "控件", i get:
    Êéß‰ª∂

for the *unicode* string, u"控件", Methods 1, 2, and 3, i get the same thing:
    Êéß‰ª∂

okay so what am i doing wrong???

Comment: well, the bytes i am getting back are actually utf8 bytes but interpreted as macRoman.  if i re-interpret them as utf8, it's correct.  but why is it macRoman?  how can i set the "default encoding" to be utf8, so i get utf8 back?  (in the c++ side, not the python side)

Comment: oops!  my fault.  i had loaded in the script to run and assumed it was macRoman.  fixed by assuming it is utf8 :D